# How to recycle app pools on EC2 instances in an autoscaling group one-at-a-time on a schedule?

Tags: amazon-ec2

We have configured a maintenance window to recycle app pools every 24 hours. The problem is that the whole autoscaling group is the target for that, so all instances are affected at once. While the goal is as follows:

- the traffic is blocked for a single instance of the autoscaling group
- the app pool is recycled on that instance
- the traffic is allowed
- the next instance is processed in the same way, etc.

I.e. it should be the same approach as OnAtATime deployment, but only app pool recycling is needed.